# Code coverage of single test file using eclemma?

Tags: java, eclemma

i am using eclemma available at http://www.eclemma.org/index.html

When i open test file, Right click --> Coverage As --> Junit Test

It shows the coverage for complete project instead of single test file under coverage view. Is there a way i can have coverage
of single test file instead of complete project ?

Comment: You can drill down into the report and get the coverage for the file you want. Is that not satisfying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the scope for code coverage, and reduce it to make the code coverage analysis run faster.

See http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/preferences.html

Comment: i could not find a wayto set the preference where i could set the coverage for only current test file and  source file for which test file is written.  Also once i run the coverage all files gets colour coded. Could n't find the way where i can get rid of those colours once i am done ?

Comment: @user3198603 Well, you typically don't select on a file basis, but on a project basis, see "coverage tab" in http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/launching.html. To get rid of the colours, see "Remove all sessions" in http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/coverageview.html (The icon with two X)